# How to handle components that can be added dynamically on page?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, web-component

How to handle components that are added on document load and also that can be inserted after the initial page load?

**Problem**

A dialog (or modal) for example, when the page loads some javascript will define the behavior, functionalities, event handlers, etc. to elements that uses the css class of component ("myDialog" in this case). Each element is an instance and the component can have multiple instances.

```
<div class="myDialog"></div>
<div class="myDialog"></div>
<div class="myDialog"></div>
<div class="myDialog"></div>
```

But what if I need to add a new dialog after the initial page load (e.g. via asynchronous request)? Will I have to upgrade all instances? and if upgrade twice the same element (instance)? How to prevent the instances to be upgraded more than once so that, for example, do not doubles the event handlers?

Believe that I don't need to use a large library/framework as React, AngularJS, Polymer among others, to only handle this task.

Is there any library that propose a design pattern for handle registration and dinamically upgrades of components at the DOM?

Comment: Who adds them? Why not just run your initialisation code only on the added elements?

Comment: @Bergi This is not the solution that I'm searching for. If I have many differents components to be upgraded I need to know every and execute their specific initialization code. What I need is make this process more easy and simpler, in other words, automatically.

Comment: You have many different components to be upgraded without knowing every specific one in the initial page as well, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking what needs to happen if you dynamically add another component (modal in your example) to your page.  If you add the same class `myDialog` to the dynamically added component, it will respond to the same event handlers that are bound to that class.  The modal components that are already there will continue to behave as they did previously.